# MongoDB querying nested documents

Tags: mongodb, nested, nested-documents

I have records like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f99cede36fd08653a3d4e92"),
    "accessions" : {
        "sample_accessions" : {
            "5f99ce9636fd08653a3d4e86" : {
                "biosampleAccession" : "SAMEA7494329",
                "sraAccession" : "ERS5250977",
                "submissionAccession" : "ERA3032827",
                "status" : "accepted"
            },
            "5f99ce9636fd08653a3d4e87" : {
                "biosampleAccession" : "SAMEA7494330",
                "sraAccession" : "ERS5250978",
                "submissionAccession" : "ERA3032827",
                "status" : "accepted"
            }
         }
     }
}
```

How do I query by the mongo id in `sample_accessions`? I thought this should work but it doesn't. What should I be doing?

```
db.getCollection('collection').find({"accessions.sample_accessions":"5f99ce9636fd08653a3d4e86"})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The id is a key and check whether key is exists or not use `$exists`, customize response using project to get specific object

```
db.getCollection('collection').find(
  {
    "accessions.sample_accessions.5f99ce9636fd08653a3d4e86": {
      $exists: true
    }
  },
  { sample_doc: "$accessions.sample_accessions.5f99ce9636fd08653a3d4e86" }
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AJiTRSd3D3k)